# Stuttering DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a time zone drop down list here:
http://sqladmin.cf/

Here is the code for it:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="tmz" class="form-control" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="-12" Text="(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-11" Text="(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-10" Text="(GMT-10:00) Hawaii" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-9" Text="(GMT-09:00) Alaska" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-8" Text="(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-8" Text="(GMT-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-7" Text="(GMT-07:00) Arizona" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-7" Text="(GMT-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-7" Text="(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-6" Text="(GMT-06:00) Central America" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-6" Text="(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-6" Text="(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-6" Text="(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-5" Text="(GMT-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-5" Text="(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-5" Text="(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-4" Text="(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-4" Text="(GMT-04:00) Caracas, La Paz" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-4" Text="(GMT-04:00) Manaus" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-4" Text="(GMT-04:00) Santiago" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-3.5" Text="(GMT-03:30) Newfoundland" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-3" Text="(GMT-03:00) Brasilia" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-3" Text="(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires, Georgetown" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-3" Text="(GMT-03:00) Greenland" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-3" Text="(GMT-03:00) Montevideo" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-2" Text="(GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is." />
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="(GMT-01:00) Azores" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="(GMT+00:00) Casablanca, Monrovia, Reykjavik" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="(GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="(GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="(GMT+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Amman" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Athens, Bucharest, Istanbul" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Beirut" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Cairo" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Harare, Pretoria" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius" />
   <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Jerusalem" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Minsk" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="(GMT+02:00) Windhoek" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="(GMT+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh, Baghdad" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="(GMT+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="(GMT+03:00) Nairobi" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="(GMT+03:00) Tbilisi" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="3.5" Text="(GMT+03:30) Tehran" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="(GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="(GMT+04:00) Baku" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="(GMT+04:00) Yerevan" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="4.5" Text="(GMT+04:30) Kabul" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="(GMT+05:00) Yekaterinburg" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="(GMT+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="5.5" Text="(GMT+05:30) Sri Jayawardenapura" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="5.5" Text="(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="5.75" Text="(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="(GMT+06:00) Almaty, Novosibirsk" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="(GMT+06:00) Astana, Dhaka" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="6.5" Text="(GMT+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="(GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="(GMT+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="(GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk, Ulaan Bataar" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="(GMT+08:00) Perth" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="(GMT+08:00) Taipei" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="(GMT+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="(GMT+09:00) Seoul" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="9.5" Text="(GMT+09:30) Adelaide" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="9.5" Text="(GMT+09:30) Darwin" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="(GMT+10:00) Brisbane" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="(GMT+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="(GMT+10:00) Hobart" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="(GMT+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="11" Text="(GMT+11:00) Magadan, Solomon Is., New Caledonia" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="12" Text="(GMT+12:00) Auckland, Wellington" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="12" Text="(GMT+12:00) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is." />
   <asp:ListItem Value="13" Text="(GMT+13:00) Nuku'alofa" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now, You will notice than upon hovering on the dropdown it has some weird effect it keeps selecting the default time zone. Can't scroll up or down and I really do not know what is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the described issue.

Comment: @David Maybe there is some kind of script that is causing the problem. I have searched the whole page and have found no scripts that are executed when the page is static